# What's faster, recursion or global variables?

Tags: python

In python, if I have a recursive function that modifies a list of integers, and assume the list is large, which is faster to do: keep the list as a global variable, and not pass it as an argument, or pass it as an argument and not make it global?

Comment: Can you show the function?

Comment: When in doubt, time it with `timeit`.

Comment: Have you tried profiling both?

Comment: I'm not sure why you wouldn't, from a function design perspective, pass in the list anyway.

Comment: Either way, the difference will be minuscule. Having it not global has the advantage of not polluting your global namespace. Plus, passing it as an argument makes the function more testable.

Comment: if passing the list as argument implicitly copy the list, use global. If passing as argument is just passing a reference then prefer argument. Speed should be the same in both cases. (unless argument copy the list).

Comment: @DarioOO -- I'm not sure what you mean -- python doesn't implicitly copy lists when you pass them around ...

Comment: @mgilson Unless you explicitly pass a slice, but then if that's the case I don't see how you could make it global.

Comment: Had issue with lists and python some time ago due to a list..

Comment: Focusing on what is "faster", as opposed to what is _cleaner_, is bad Python anyhow. If you care about fast more than you care about clean, you should be using different tools.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lists are passed by adress, so extra overhead is just single function parameter (pointer). I dont think it is noticeable.

You have to test yourself, but I would be surprised if it would be significant.

Comment: Python passes references by value for *everything* anyways (ie: there's no such thing as pass by value in Python)

Comment: Passing immutable types ends up looking a lot like pass-by-value, since changes made in the function do not affect the value in the caller.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Well, when you have an immutable type you *can't* make changes to the object by definition. I suppose the behavior you're describing is something like `def fun(x): x = <something>`. In this case, the result is the same whether the object is mutable or not.

Answer (score 1):

For fast and clean code, you should use an iterative approach to recursion (as far as there's no algorithmic alternative) with a custom stack, instead of globals.

Answer (score 0):

If the list is passed by reference and not duplicated in the recursive function, then the performance difference will be negligible, and you should use whichever method will result in more clear and maintainable code. Usually this would be passing the array as a parameter, but not always.